# Why do the $L_z$ and $L^2$ operators share eigenfunctions, but the $L_x$ and $L_y$ operators don't?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, angular-momentum, operators, commutator, observables

In my lecture notes the following was written:

[image]

[image]

I would understand in the case of an applied field if there was some symmetry breaking feature which would allow for a preferred axis or something which could explain why the $L_z$ operator and $L^2$ operator share eigenfunctions as mentioned in the above notes.

I would've thought in the case of no external field, there is no reason to assume the x y and z axis's have any distinguishing factor between them.

Why does this happen?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is possible to have a simultaneous eignfunction of ${\hat L}^2$ and one other component of the angular momentum. Typically this is taken to be ${\hat L}_z$, but it could just as well be the $x$ or $y$ component - there is nothing special about $z$. This is known as "choosing a quantization axis".

Answer (score 2):

The reason is quite simple:

The operators $\hat{L}^2$ and $\hat{L}_z$ have common eigen-functions
because they commute with each other, i.e. $[\hat{L}^2,\hat{L_z}]=0$.

The operators $\hat{L}_x$ and $\hat{L}_y$ don't have common eigen-functions
because they don't commute with each other, i.e. $[\hat{L}_x,\hat{L}_y]\ne 0$.

So the reason is just the algebraic relations between the angular momentum operators.
An external field is not relevant for the reasoning.

Comment: Im guessing the reasoning is in the maths for why they dont commute. But its still pretty strange that only 1 direction commutes with the $L^2$ operator.

Comment: That is not the case, ${\hat L}_x$ and ${\hat L}_y$ also commute with ${\hat L}^2$. But the components of angular momentum do not commute with each other.

Comment: @VishalJain It is not only $L_z$ commuting with $L^2$.
$L_x$ and $L_y$ commute with $L^2$ as well.
It is just a convention to pick $L_z$ for the eigenfunctions.
You could have picked $L_x$ or $L_y$ instead of $L_z$.